# Rails, Testing json response when javascript is also returned

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, json, integration-testing, minitest

I am new to rails and currently trying to test responses for endpoints that return JavaScript and JSON as a response. My issue is I can only seem to view the JavaScript response and returning statuses just blocks the JavaScript from being executed. I have looked everywhere but cannot seem to find an answer to my current issue.
Below is the code I am trying to test

```
respond_to do |format|
     if @comment.update(comment)
       format.json { render :news, status: :success, location: @comment }
       format.js   { }
     else
       format.json { render json: @comment.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
       format.js   { }
    end
end
```

I have tried returning status responses like below to test for the status rather than reading the JSON

```
head(422)
```

and

```
format.js { head :unprocessable_entity }
```

While these seem to work in terms of getting the response back they also seem to block the JavaScript from being executed.
When trying to assert the contents of the body I can only seem to read the JavaScript, the JSON does not seem to be present.

```
 put update_comment_url(@comment), params: { comment: { uncensored: @comment.uncensored, id_reference: @comment.id_reference, page_type: @comment.page_type, replied_to: @comment.replied_to, user_id: @comment } }, xhr: true
```

When explicitly requesting a certain format like below

```
put update_comment_url(@comment), params: { comment: { uncensored: @comment.uncensored, id_reference: @comment.id_reference, page_type: @comment.page_type, replied_to: @comment.replied_to, user_id: @comment },  :format => 'json'  }, xhr: true
```

This just causes an error to be thrown as it expects a view to be present of which does not exist.
I am more than likely misunderstanding some concepts here but I hope someone can point me in the right direction.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case anybody new to rails is looking for the same answer I have figured it out after some trial and error. Simply putting the required format in parentheses like so seems to work for me.

```
put update_comment_url(@comment, format: :json), params: { comment: { uncensored: @comment.uncensored, id_reference: @comment.id_reference, page_type: @comment.page_type, replied_to: @comment.replied_to, user_id: @comment }}, xhr: true
```